# mysql user login

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have created a user Sam with password mypass for my database db.

How to login with this user.

I want to check the privileges privided to this user.

I am using MYSQL 5.5

i am using windows 7. mysql command line.

Comment: Could you provide more detail about how you are accessing the database? Do you have a control panel? Is this from a shell? From an application? Which operating system?

Comment: windows 7.mysql command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging in is as simple as:

```
mysql -u Sam -p
```

You should then be prompted for your password. At this point, you'd either have to select a database to do operations on it or you could check your grants in general.

Checking user privileges is as simple as:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
```

I would highly recommend reading [MySQL :: Getting Started with MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html).

Comment: mysql> create user sam identified by 'mypass'

Comment: mysql> -u sam -p;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-u sam -p' at line 1

Comment: Sameer: you would use that username and password from the command line or from an external application. If you're in the MySQL prompt already, you've already logged in.